# windows server 2008 r2 ftp setup help + filezilla server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp

Hey all i have followed this page to a "T": http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/321/configure-ftp-with-iis-7-manager-authentication/

in setting up the FTP server. I have also done the firewall thing with the svchost giving that permission.

I use the command prompt to test the ftp and i always get

```
ftp>
```

It never asked me for a user name or password.

When i type this into a browser:

```
ftp.myservernamehere.com:30001
```

it prompts me for a username and password which i enter what i added in those steps above and it never logs me in!!!! Keeps asking for username and password!!!

What in the world am i doing wrong?!?!?

David

**When running IIS7 FTP**

```
    [R] Connecting to ftp.domain.com -> DNS=ftp.domain.com IP=**.***.***.*** PORT=30001
[R] Connected to ftp.domain.com
[R] 220 Microsoft FTP Service
[R] USER theuser
[R] 331 Password required for theuser
[R] PASS (hidden)
[R] 230 User logged in.
[R] SYST
[R] 215 Windows_NT
[R] FEAT
[R] 211-Extended features supported:
[R]  LANG EN*
[R]  UTF8
[R]  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
[R]  PBSZ
[R]  PROT C;P;
[R]  CCC
[R]  HOST
[R]  SIZE
[R]  MDTM
[R]  REST STREAM
[R] 211 END
[R] CWD /
[R] 250 CWD command successful.
[R] PWD
[R] 257 "/" is current directory.
[R] TYPE A
[R] 200 Type set to A.
[R] PASV
[R] 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,20,192,246).
[R] Opening data connection IP: **.***.***.*** PORT: 49398
[R] Data Socket Error: Connection refused
[R] List Error
[R] PASV
[R] 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,20,192,247).
[R] Opening data connection IP: **.***.***.*** PORT: 49399
[R] Data Socket Error: Connection refused
[R] List Error
```

**When running Filezilla server log**

```
Creating listen socket on port 30001...
Server online
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - (not logged in) (**.***.***.***)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - (not logged in) (**.***.***.***)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.37 beta
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - (not logged in) (**.***.***.***)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - (not logged in) (**.***.***.***)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - (not logged in) (**.***.***.***)> USER userhere
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - (not logged in) (**.***.***.***)> 331 Password required for userhere
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - (not logged in) (**.***.***.***)> PASS *******
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 230 Logged on
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> SYST
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> FEAT
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 211-Features:
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)>  MDTM
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)>  REST STREAM
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)>  SIZE
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)>  MLST type*;size*;modify*;
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)>  MLSD
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)>  UTF8
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)>  CLNT
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)>  MFMT
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 211 End
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> CLNT FlashFXP 3.0.1044
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 200 Don't care
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> CWD /
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> PWD
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> TYPE A
(000027)12/15/2010 9:33:08 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 200 Type set to A
(000026)12/15/2010 9:19:37 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> PORT 192,168,1,7,4,166
(000026)12/15/2010 9:19:37 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 200 Port command successful
(000026)12/15/2010 9:19:37 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> LIST -al
(000026)12/15/2010 9:19:37 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 150 Opening data channel for directory list.
(000026)12/15/2010 9:19:38 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 425 Can't open data connection.
(000026)12/15/2010 9:19:45 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> TYPE I
(000026)12/15/2010 9:19:45 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 200 Type set to I
(000026)12/15/2010 9:19:45 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> SIZE GS108T-V3.0.4.10.hex
(000026)12/15/2010 9:19:45 AM - userhere (**.***.***.***)> 550 File not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend that you stop using the command prompt and certainly stop using Internet Explorer for connecting to an FTP. Use a decent FTP program instead, something like FileZilla which will show you the server responses you receive which you can use to resolve your login issues.

As for the lonely `ftp>`, if you start a command prompt and type `ftp` you'll get nothing more than an `ftp>` prompt. 
You need to type in `open ftp.domain.com` at this prompt before you'll be requested to log in with a username or password (unless you typed `ftp ftp.domain.com` in the first instance!)

So, two options:

`C:\Users\User>ftp`

`ftp>open ftp.domain.com:30001`

or

`C:\Users\User>ftp ftp.domain.com:30001`

I've got an FTP running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS Manager users so if you need anything further, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Lewis. I did do the ftp ftp.domain.com:30001 and it still just gives me that ftp> line without being able to type in the user name and password..

Comment: I've got filezilla server up and working on it but i can not seem to connect using passive mode or upload a file without it telling me **425 Can't open data connection.** See OP for the list of what its doing when trying to upload a file.

Comment: @StealthRT: why in the world did you install FileZilla **server** on a box where IIS's own FTP service is running? Lewis was suggesting you to use the FileZilla **client** :-) Having two FTP servers on the same box isn't going to help you much.

Comment: @Massimo. I turned off the MSFTP when i tested the filezilla server. And i turned off filezilla server when testing MSFTP. I'm using Bulletproof FTP to log into the server.

Comment: @StealthRT: of course, otherwise they wouldn't work :-) I was only saying that changing your FTP server isn't going to solve your client/connection problems, unless the IIS FTP service was severely misconfigured.

Comment: I finally got the MS FTP server working but i still get the **Data Socket Error: Connection refused** and **List Error** :o( Check my OP for log. I seem to be unable to enter anything in the **Data Channel Port Range** in the Server Manager. Its disabled and i guess that may have something to do with it?

Comment: @StealthRT: As Massimo said, I didn't mean for you to install the FileZilla server, just the client. Internet Explorer and the command prompt FTP client included in Windows aren't exactly "user friendly".
You mentioned that the Data Channel Port Range is disabled. It isn't, you're just looking in the wrong place. Instead of clicking on the FTP site, click on the server (top level node in IIS) and then click FTP Firewall Support in the Features view. You can edit the Data Channel Port Range there. If you're getting a connection refused message, check that your firewall is open for those ports.

Comment: @StealthRT: After you have changed your Data Channel Port Range and confirmed there's a firewall rule (usually created by default), you should check that Basic Authentication and, if you want to use it, IISManagerAuth is added (and enabled!) to FTP Authentication. Click on your FTP site, from the Features view double-click FTP Authentication then, in the Actions pane, click Custom Providers... Select the check box next to IisManagerAuth and click OK.
IIS Manager Users are added at the Server level. You can then add the created user to sub-folders of the FTP site using FTP Authorization Rules.

Comment: @StealthRT: If you want to use FTP User Isolation, you must set up a specific folder structure under your FTP site. I'm assuming you're not implementing this with Domain based authentication so the folder structure looks like this...
[FTP Site]\LocalUser\UserName
So, for a user called Stealth you would create a folder called LocalUser and in that, you create a folder called Stealth.
Assuming your FTP site root is C:\inetpub\ftproot, the folder structure would be C:\inetpub\ftproot\LocalUser\Stealth.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first problem (authentication): IIS's FTP service has lots and lots of authentication options, so there could be many reasons why it's not letting you in. The most common cause is logging in as an user which doesn't have read permissions on the root FTP directory, but there could be many, many more.

Regarding your second problem (unable to open data connection): this is usually a firewall issue. Where are you trying to connect from? Do you have the same problem if you run the client and the server on the same machine? Have you tried completely turning off Windows Firewall?

Comment: Ok, i finally added the user to the **Local Useres and Groups** and i am now able to log into the FTP via the MS FTP server. However, i am still getting the **Data Socket Error: Connection refused** and **List Error** :o( Check my OP for log.

Comment: @StealthRT: you dind't answer my questions; where is the server and where is the client? Are they on the same computer? On the same network? On different networks? If you try to run both on the same computer, does it work? This is very likely a network and/or firewall problem, so nothing can be said unless you tell more about your network setup.